# sam local start-api go lambda returns 502 "internal server error" on linux ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

While running aws sam application locally returns "Internal server error".

I created aws sam hello-world example using:

```
sam init --runtime go1.x --name robertsamlocallyhelloworld
```

then I run app locally using:

```
sam local start-api
```

then:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:3000/hello
```

Image downloading has started and then stopped after a while.

`/hello` endpoint returns: `502 "Internal server error"`

I am using:
Sam Cli: 1.15.0
Docker: 20.10.0

Output:

```
Invoking hello-world (go1.x)<br>
Image was not found.<br>
Building image....................................<br>
Skip pulling image and use local one: amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-go1.x:rapid-1.15.0.<br>

Mounting /home/robert/projects/try_dir/try_sam_go_daemons/robertsamlocallyhelloworld/hello-world as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container<br>
START RequestId: 159c8e80-649d-4c71-8b54-3221387af308 Version: $LATEST<br>
fork/exec /var/task/hello-world: no such file or directory: PathError<br>
null<br>
END RequestId: 159c8e80-649d-4c71-8b54-3221387af308<br>
REPORT RequestId: 159c8e80-649d-4c71-8b54-3221387af308  Init Duration: 0.38 ms  Duration: 9.30 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB <br>
Lambda returned empty body!<br>
Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'errorMessage', 'errorType'} in {'errorMessage': 'fork/exec /var/task/hello-world: no such file or directory', 'errorType': 'PathError'}<br>
2021-01-11 23:55:41 127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2021 23:55:41] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 502 <br>
2021-01-11 23:55:41 127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2021 23:55:41] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 <br>
```

Comment: It is obvious that the error is  'fork/exec /var/task/hello-world: no such file or directory'
means ```sam local start-api``` has problem

Comment: I solved it. After ```init``` I run ```make``` or ```sam build```.

Answer (score 5):

The error message clearly states:

```
Invalid API Gateway Response Keys
```

I faced a similar error in which I received error for the response status_code:

```
Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'status_code'} in {'status_code': 200, 'body': '"Success!!"'}
```

Apparently, SAM tries to mock the API Gateway and status_code was not one of the keys API Gateway expects in the response. Therefor I changed it to key from `status_code` to `statusCode`

```
    return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps("Success!!")
}
```

And, it worked fine.

I would suggest you take a look at API Gateway response keys and try to map your response to that.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error because the local invocation doesn't have access to environment variables referenced in the template.yml.
eg.:

```yaml
...
 #template.yml
     Policies:
    # Give Create/Read/Update/Delete Permissions to the SampleTable
    - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
        TableName: !Ref SampleTable
  Environment:
    Variables:
      # Make table name accessible as environment variable from function code during execution
      SAMPLE_TABLE: !Ref SampleTable

...
```

One solution is to deploy the app and fetch the env variables from the console, then input them into a "env.json" or similar:

```json
{
"getAllItemsFunction": {
    "SAMPLE_TABLE": "dev-demo-SampleTable-*ID*"
},}
```

Then you can use the deployed table in your local development by adding `-e env.json` to the `sam local invoke command`.
Like this:

```
sam local invoke getAllItemsFunction -e events/event-get-all-items.json -n env.json
```

Honestly  dont know where the connection between SAMPLE_TABLE and "!Ref SampleTable" is happening, but it works.
Take a look at this: https://youtu.be/NzPqMrdgD1s?t=799

Answer (score 0):

Same answer I wrote on https://stackoverflow.com/a/72067740/93074

So from the following tutorial covering [how to get lambdas and api-gateway working using CDK](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-api-gateway-example), I managed to isolate that without the following line will result in the 502 BAD GATEWAY error experienced, with the suggested return type as described. It's in the `new apigateway.RestApi` props.

```
defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
...
        allowOrigins: ['http://localhost:3000'],
      },
```

The op doesn't specify his infrastructure propositioning method. If not using the CDK and using Cloud Formation YAML then it's *probably* related to the equivalent in the expanded YAML (although the net result of the expansion is beyond my competency).

`method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

```yaml
BrokerAPItest41BB435C:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt 'BrokerAPID825C3CC.RootResourceId'
      PathPart: test
      RestApiId: !Ref 'BrokerAPID825C3CC'
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: BrokerAwsDeployStack/BrokerAPI/Default/test/Resource
  BrokerAPItestOPTIONS843EE5C3:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      ResourceId: !Ref 'BrokerAPItest41BB435C'
      RestApiId: !Ref 'BrokerAPID825C3CC'
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '''Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'''
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '''http://localhost:3000'''
              method.response.header.Vary: '''Origin'''
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: '''OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD'''
            StatusCode: '204'
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: '{ statusCode: 200 }'
        Type: MOCK
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            method.response.header.Vary: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
          StatusCode: '204'
    Metadata:
```